# Fluent bit - How can I check for internal errors?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, fluent-bit

I installed fluent bit using YAML files on my K8s instance following the [documentation](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/kubernetes/). I just modified the Elasticsearch instance pointing to my own instance.

All fluent-bit daemonsets are running but it is not sending any logs to my ES.

I checked pods logs in every node and I don't see any errors, just "stream processor started" messages.

Is there any other way to check for errors on fluent bit beside "kubectl logs" on daemontsets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try mofifying the `fluent-bit.conf [SERVICE]` section of the `fluent-bit-config` ConfigMap to something like this:

```yaml
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     debug <--- Change this to debug
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server   On
        HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port     2020

    @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE output-elasticsearch.conf
```

Then restart the fluent-bit pod(s)

```sh
kubectl delete pod fluent-bit-xxxxx
```

You'll get a lot of logs so you may not want to keep that pod up for a long time. After you are done debugging you can follow the same procedure to change it back to `info`.

Comment: I'm running my k8s on CentOS and docker was using journal as logging driver. And I figured out this because a fluent bit warning showing up about /var/log/containers/ folder being empty. Thank you!